# Why in Android NDK not Install Software?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I Start the Android NDK and create error in Console "ObjectAid Sequence Diagram is not available because no valid license was found"..

Please give me Solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That has most likely nothing to do with the Android NDK, but another software called [ObjectAid Sequence Diagram](http://www.objectaid.com/sequence-diagram) which requires an evaluation or paid license:

> Note that you need a license to use the Sequence Diagram Editor. To obtain a license, first create an account by clicking on Account. Once your account has been activated, you can request a single evaluation license or purchase single-user licenses for 19 USD each.
>
> from http://www.objectaid.com/download